# Is it idiomatic to say "There are some chips on the wall"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, vocabulary

> **chip** (n) 4 MARK a small hole or mark on a plate, cup etc where a piece
>   has broken off
>
> **chip in**    There’s a chip in this bowl.

The edge of a wall is very prone to get broken since hard objects might bump into it when being carried by people. This might cause some small holes in the wall (see the picture)

[image]

Is it idiomatic to say "**There are some chips on the wall**"? (I am not sure we use "**in**" or "**on**").

The dictionary suggests "**in**", but [this video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqIL9TA1Nj0) says "**on**".

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but rather unusual, to talk about "chips in/on the wall"

Its more likely that only the paint is damaged:

> There's a chip in the paint here.
>
> The paint is chipped.

Or you could use "damaged"

> To prevent damage to the paintwork, plastic covers can be fitted to protruding corners.

Comment: In any case I would say the correct preposition is "in" and not "on."